# What will be the sum of the series of binomial co-efficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

What will be the sum of the following binomial co-efficent series

$$\binom{z+1}{z} + \binom{z+2}{z} + \binom{z+3}{z} + \dots + \binom{z+r}{z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^r \binom{z+i}{z}$$

Thank you

Comment: Look up the hockey-stick identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Add $\binom{z+1}{z+1}$ to you sum and use $\binom{k}{z}+\binom{k}{z+1}=\binom{k+1}{z+1}$ repeatedly:

$$\binom{z+1}{z+1}+\binom{z+1}{z} + \binom{z+2}{z} + \binom{z+3}{z} + \dots + \binom{z+r}{z} \\
=\binom{z+2}{z+1}+\binom{z+2}{z} + \binom{z+3}{z} + \dots + \binom{z+r}{z} \\=...$$

Here I am using the standard notation $\binom{k}{z}$ for $_kC_z$.

**P.S.** You can also see this formula backwards: using
$$\binom{z+k}{z}=\binom{z+k+1}{z+1}-\binom{z+k}{z+1}$$
you sum becomes telescopic.

Answer (score 1):

$\dbinom{z+1}{z} +\dbinom{z+2}{z} +\cdots+\dbinom{z+r}{z}$

= Coeff of $x^{z}$ in $(1+x)^{z+1}$+ Coeff of $x^{z}$ in $(1+x)^{z+2}$+$\cdots$+ Coeff of $x^{z}$ in $(1+x)^{z+r}$

= Coeff of $x^{z}$ in $((1+x)^{z+1}+ (1+x)^{z+2}+\cdots+ (1+x)^{z+r})$

= Coeff of $x^{z}$ in $((1+x)^{z+1}\frac{(1+x)^{r}-1}{1+x-1})$

= Coeff of $x^{z+1}$ in $((1+x)^{z+1}.((1+x)^{r}-1))$

= Coeff of $x^{z+1}$ in $((1+x)^{z+r+1}-(1+x)^{z+1})$

=$\dbinom{z+r+1}{z+1}-\dbinom{z+1}{z+1}$

=$\dbinom{z+r+1}{r}-1$